# How to pass global variable to a referenced assembly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, global-variables

How to pass global variable to a referenced assembly?

I am modifying an asp.net app. It is required to log all Employee (the current user of the website) actions like saving a new customer or update invoice data.  The UI layer is calling a referenced assembly BLL.dll.

I want to pass current Emplyee to the referenced assembly.  The passed Employee should be **shared accross all static methods in that dll**. It should be thread safe because the Employee can be changed accross requests.

**I can't expose static field in the BLL** because the Employee is stored in session state.

**I need something not static, Global, accessible by both assemblies (UI layer and BLL.dll), and thread safe.**

I am thinking about using some variable stored in current thread object.  but I don't know what exactly I should do??

Any workarrounds ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need something in your BLL that can get the reference. You can use a strategy pattern with an interface.

```
// IN BLL.dll

public interface IEmployeeContextImplementation 
{
   Employee Current { get; }
}

public static EmployeeContext 
{
   private static readonly object ImplementationLock = new object();
   private static IEmployeeContextImplementation Implementation;

   public static void SetImplementation(IEmployeeContextImplementation impl)
   {
      lock(ImplementationLock)
      {
         Implementation = impl;
      }
   }
   public static Employee Current { get { return Implementation.Current; }
}
```

Then in your web app, implement `IEmployeeContextImplementation` with the session state and call `SetImplementation` only once in application start.

However, Session state is only good enough for within the context of a request. If you need it to go on a different thread, you will have to explicitly pass it to a different thread.

Comment: Nice solution, it should work.  I don't think we need the lock anymore because Sessions are thread safe.

Comment: the lock is there incase something else is trying to set the implementation.